# How to fix this error creating Foreign Key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I've got two tables in a PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE anillamientos
(gbifid integer NOT NULL,
specieskey integer,
localidad integer)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE sitios
(gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sitios_gid_seq'::regclass),
nombre character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
detalles character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
CONSTRAINT sitios_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid))
```

I want to create a foreign key in the first table that references the second one on the field `gid`. I have built the following code

```
alter table anillamientos 
add constraint fk_anill_sitio 
foreign key (localidad) references sitios(gid);
```

But it returns the following error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "anillamientos" violates foreign key constraint "fk_anill_sitio"
DETAIL:  Key (localidad)=(1) is not present in table "sitios".
SQL state: 23503
```

What does that mean? I have checked that id 1 is present in both tables. Why doesn't it work and how can it be solved?

Comment: Just to be clear, in `sitios` there is a row with a `gid` of 1? Is the table `sitios` present in multiple schemas? If so are hitting a `search_path` issue where the FK is trying to refer to a version that does not have a `gid` of 1?

Comment: Yes, there is a row in `sitios` with `gid` = 1; and no, the table `sitios` is only present in the `public` schema.

Comment: Then I would suspect a corrupt index on `sitios`. Try `REINDEX sitios`.

Comment: The very same error occurs after reindexing

Comment: Hmm, not sure what is going on.  The only thing I can think to do now is create a duplicate table of `sitios` like  `CREATE TABLE sitios_dup AS SELECT * FROM sitios`, assuming the table is not so large as to create a performance/storage issue  . Then point `anillamientos` at the duplicate table, at least temporarily, to see what happens.